# How to change the colored cell values into special character using excel macro or by excel formulas?

Tags: excel, vba

How do i change the colored cell values.

Using conditional formatting I have changed the cell value into red using a condition

- cell value is = less than or equal to(zero)

After that I want to change those red colored cell values filled with '-'.

Comment: @pnuts hmmm good point: not thought of that interpretation..suspect `VBA` would then be the route to take.

Answer (score 2):

Create a "Custom" format for the target cells:

In the Type window you have 3 areas divided by semi-colons:

```
£#,##0.00;-;-
```

The first section will be applied to positive numbers - the second to negative and the third to zero. Just type in the formats you want.

[image]

Works like this:

[image]